# Test JpaRepository findById returns null for UUID

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Spring newbie here,
I want to test the the `findById()` method of a repository, but it cannot find the entry even through it is saved (and exists) in the database:

```
@DataJpaTest
class CustomerRepoIntegration {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepo customerRepo;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void findById() {
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        Customer customer = new Customer(uuid);
        customerRepo.save(customer);

        List<Customer> allCustomers = customerRepo.findAll();
        assertEquals(1, allCustomers.size());

        Optional<Customer> foundCustomer = customerRepo.findById(uuid);
        assertTrue(foundCustomer.isPresent());
    }
}
```

While the first assert is successful the second fails with:

```
Error:  Failures: 
Error:    CustomerRepoIntegration.findById:32 expected: <true> but was: <false>
```

---

The rest of the code:

```
// CustomerRepo.java
public interface CustomerRepo extends JpaRepository<Customer, UUID> {}
```

```
// Customer.java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    private UUID id;
}
```

I also made a reproduction repo here: https://github.com/ofhouse/stackoverflow-65818312

Comment: The id is generated by the database. So the id you assign is being lost. Instead use `customer.getId()` to find it again. Also using `@Data` with an `@Entity` is a bad idea. (see https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/).

Comment: Indeed, the auto generated id was the problem here. Thanks for the hint when using `@Data` and `@Entity` together. Great read, didn't know about this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

`customerRepo.saveAndFlush(customer)` instead `save(customer)`

Moreover, if you have configured an entity annotation responsible for auto-generating the id, the better idea would be not interfering in this mechanism creating your own UUID and initialize the entity. Hibernate will do it automatically for you.

Why not?

Hibernate has its own mechanism depends on the marked field with `@Id` annotation whether to merge or persist entity with EntityManager (If the field is null or contains data).

Instead of

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
Customer customer = new Customer(uuid);
```

You can simply do

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
```

And fetch UUID from a persisted instance of entity here:

```
var persistedCustomer = customerRepo.saveAndFlush(customer);
...
Optional<Customer> foundCustomer = customerRepo.findById(persistedCustomer.uuid);
```

Comment: Yup, Use saveAndFlush.  Try removing @Transactional annotation also that may fix the issue.

Comment: Flushing happens automatically before querying so it doesn't have an effect here. Removing the `@Transactional` would be plain wrong, because it would run the test in a completely unrealistic setting (without transaction) which also could trigger all kinds of problems and finally would leave data in the table which will interfere with future test runs of the same or other tests. The problem is with the UUID generation.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the helpful answers and comments here! Key was that the UUID was overridden by the auto generated value. Updated the example repo with the fix: https://github.com/ofhouse/stackoverflow-65818312/commit/b415de0f2b1b7457db22bfeadab206e8e6f9d944

Answer (score 1):

For people using spring-boot 2.7.X, which ships with hibernate-core:5.6.10 the actual problem is explained [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11490).

By adding columnDefinition = "uuid" to the  UUID @Column() definition the problem was solved on h2.